# is there a method like 'get_meta_tags' in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to extract the meta-tags from an url, especially the title and the description but i don't know how to do this. I tried with http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.2/api/http.html#http.request but i get errors like '411'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node only parses HTTP, not HTML or other content types.  Thankfully, there is a full DOM implementation for node here:

https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom

Load up your HTML content there, and that'll get you pretty close to your PHP example.